# How do I consume openAM services from my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, openam

I am new to openAM. And I am trying to consume one of our partner applications that use openAM to authenticate user. My task is to create a link from our application on button click to make our user go to our partner application. Without log in again, since our user already logged in. Our partner configure openAM and gave me a url that land in to open AM page. How can I log in to our partner page without log in again?(Since user already log in in our application) How do I consume open AM as a service since our partner will be a service provider?  Is there a link or good tutorial about this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit vague, but you may look at

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+and+ADFS2+configuration

as a starting point

Comment: sorry for that, My question is how to configure openAM as identity provider?  How does my Application  consume our partner service? I just want to give our user capability of navigating to our partner application without log in since they did when they land to my application.

Comment: About OpenAM and SAMLv2...
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/admin-guide/index.html#chap-federation